# MY zip folder is locked

Tags: 16.10

i just downloaded a zip file of a game called sims 4,am trying to send it to my flash drive but the keep telling i don't have permision and it shows that the file is locked.So how can i unlock and send this file to my flash drive?

Comment: where is your flash drive mounted?  assuming it's on `/media/mount`, can you paste the output of `ll /media/mount` here? you mach change your username in the post for confidentiality.

Comment: please also include the output of `ll <path_to_your_zip_file>`

Answer (score 1):

The file could possibly be owned by root, but this is unlikely unless you downloaded it as root from the command line. In nautilus (your file browser), files for which you don't have write permissions show the "lock" symbol.

More likely, especially if you mounted the flash drive manually, your flash drive's mount point has root ownership. The default directory permissions only allow the owner of the directory to write.

Running `mount` will tell you where your flash drive is mounted.  Assuming it's mounted to `/mount/point`, running `ll /mount/point` will show you the owner and group of this directory.

If it is `root:root`, you need to take ownership of the directory so that you can write and manage files graphically in nautilus. Run

`sudo chown <your_username>:<your_username> /mount/point`

and try to copy the zip over again.

This will allow you write to the flash drive in nautilus, since in the GUI, you are your user, not root.

Comment: What about 'gksu nautilus'' to copy / unzip to flash drive?

Comment: this would be a good graphical solution, in keeping with the graphical references in the question; however, this would have to be invoked every time the flash drive is mounted, and could also lead to important file destruction.